# Using a json to create MySQL table

Tags: mysql, json

If I have a list of json objects that describe SQL columns, like so:

```
[{'type': 'int4', 'id': '_id'},  
{'type': 'text', 'id': 'month'},  
{'type': 'text', 'id': 'town'}]
```

Is there any native features in MySQL that allows me to create a table using this list of json objects, instead of hardcoding my CREATE TABLE statement?

A sample create table statement would be:

CREATE TABLE house
             (_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
              month varchar,
town varchar)

Comment: What would your SQL for this example input be?

Comment: And how is this a Python question ?

Comment: In which language is this json list is getting? You can use foreach loop if using php. First convert it to array and then apply foreach loop to get column names and data type and get `CREATE TABLE` statement and run `mysqli_query`.

Answer (score 0):

No, MySQL does not have any built-in features to infer a table design from your JSON sample.